# Filter observable array by value of observable property?

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream of emissions conforming to: `Observable<Notice[]>`. Each `Notice` has a property, `isVisible$` (`Observable<boolean>`) that determines whether or not it is on screen in this particular moment. I want to filter this array of notices by whether the most recent value of `isVisible$` is `true`. When a new `array` of notices occurs, I want to begin the process again. I know this entails using `switchMap` on the higher order observable stream.

Neither types of observable will ever complete, so using operators like `toArray()` will not work here. Each `isVisible$` stream is guaranteed to emit at least once.

I want the output to also be of `Observable<Notice[]>`, emitting each time the `isVisible$` stream of any of the inner observable predicates updates.

What I have so far does emit the proper values, but the inner pipeline just groups notices together and emits them (via `scan`, in lieu of `toArray`), it doesn't buffer to the length of `from(notices)` and *then* emit (if that makes sense). This makes the end result of the stream is too busy.

```js
notices.pipe(
  switchMap(notices => from(notices).pipe(
    mergeMap(notice => notice.isVisible$.pipe(
      map(isVisible => ({ notice, isVisible }))
    )),
    filter(({ isVisible }) => isVisible),
    map(({ notice }) => notice),
    scan((noticesArr, noticeBeingAddedOrRemoved) => {
      if (!noticesArr.find(n => n.identifier === noticeBeingAddedOrRemoved.id)) {
        noticesArr.push(noticeBeingAddedOrRemoved);
      }
      return noticesArr;
    }, [])
  ))
);
```

[Here's a reproducible sample of what I'm working with on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q1cl18?file=index.ts).

Comment: If you need to wait for all of the `isVisible` observables to emit you can look at using [zip](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip) or [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin), although the latter requires all of the input observables to complete. To use this you could do something like `take(1)` on each to ensure it completes.

Comment: @NickL I've thought about that, but unfortunately the `isVisible` observables also can emit indefinitely. If no update to the higher-order observable is received, then updates to the isVisible observables will occur until the application is destroyed.

I'm playing around with `bufferCount` at the moment as a way of reducing the inner observables to the expected count of `notice`'s.

Comment: I've added an answer, but I'm not sure if it's exactly what you wanted. It would be helpful if you could show exactly what you expect to be emitted in your stackblitz example. Or draw something like a [marble diagram](https://rxmarbles.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed it to [use zip](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jjjfnu?file=index.ts), which will only emit when each of the isVisible$ observables emit. You could also use `combineLatest` if you want to emit whenever *any* of the source observables emit, rathern than waiting for *all* of them.